# boost on linux ubuntu server 11.10 (vps) compiling with C++ using asio

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost, boost-asio

I Followed the guide for unix. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html. It works fine on my mac. But on my VPS I seem to be having a few issues. I downloaded the latest build and ran bootstrap and b2 install and the example.cpp worked fine.

When I tired to compile the boost udp echo server - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp

I get following error.

```
andrew@am:~/Documents/boostExamples/asyncUdpEchoServer$ c++ -I /usr/local/boost main.cpp -o udpEchoServer
/tmp/cczYAR1r.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x232): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cczYAR1r.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cczYAR1r.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x7): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas what I need to do here?   -  I was sort if under the influence that you don't need to build boost.

The vps is running ubuntu server 11.10 but it seems to be a little cut down. I have installed build-essential.

Comment: Not all parts of boost are header-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must link boost_system lib: `-lboost_system`. Also dont forget to specify lib directory if need.